# Quirkiness in Haskell 7.8.3

Tags: haskell

I have 2 functions in a plain file with nothing else.

```
--This is FN1
helper :: Int -> Double -> Double
helper n x = (nu/d)
  where
    nu = x^n 
    d = product [1 .. n]

--This is FN2
filterOdd :: [a] -> [a] 
filterOdd ls = fi ls [1..]
  where
    fi [] _ = []
    fi (v:vs) (i:ix) = if even i
                        then v:(fi vs ix) 
                        else fi vs ix
```

I am using GHC 7.8.3

I know that there is a type error in FN1. I am aware of that.
When FN1 is commented and run, GHCi throws no errors.
But when FN1 is uncommented and run GHCi show the obvious error in FN1, but also a 2 page long error for FN2.

I don't understand this. There is no explicit relationship between FN1 and FN2. Nothing in FN1 is calling FN2 and vice versa. But why does GHCi show errors for FN2 when FN1 is uncommented?

The exact error is long enough, that I decided to put it on [lpaste](http://lpaste.net/2148589949971070976)

Could someone please tell me, what is going on? Mostly likely, I have misunderstood something.

Comment: I can observe the same behavior (in the same version of GHC), but I can't explain it. It looks pretty weird. I'm looking forward to an answer.

Comment: In `7.6.3` no such error occurs...

Comment: [here's the trace](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/23136f5a74d2beb33cb6) from the typechecker. GHC version 7.8.3

Comment: Perhaps ghc slackens off normal defaulting rules or turns on some extension or other in a vain effort to compile FN1, which then introduces unresolved ambiguity in the type of the numeric literals.

Comment: Smaller example: `fn1::a` `fn1 x = x x` `idxs xs = if even 1 then [] else xs`

Comment: This sure looks like a GHC bug triggered by having a defaultable `Num` expression buried in the function--`[1..]` in your example, `even 1` in @AndrewC's. Have you reached out to the GHC team?

Comment: 50 lines is *not* long at all. Consider moving things outside the question when they reach like 500+ lines. Below that, they can stay "inline" without any problem.

Comment: Even more problematic is that one gets the same error messages  when `FN1` comes _after_ `FN2`, in which case the spurious error messages come _before_ the real one. Most people will try to repair the first error they see, which will lead them nowhere in that case....

Comment: I've seen this problem in a lot of places but don't know enough about GHC to know why its happening. It is certainly a bug, since the 2nd function doesn't even use the first. The "quick fix" is give `fi` a monomorphic type signature (`fi :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]`) or give a type signature at its invokation so that defaulting isn't used (`fi ls [1 :: Int ..]`).

Comment: @ChristianConkle Haven't reached out to the GHC team. Am gonna give it a few more hours to see if someone can answer it.

Comment: I can't answer it, but this doesn't happen any more (for this test case, at least) in GHC 7.10.1RC1. I don't have 7.8.4, so I don't know if the fix was back-ported, but I would guess it likely was not. As for the details, it seems to make no difference what type error occurs in `helper`, as long as there *is* a type error, but replacing `filterOdd` with something non-polymorphic makes the weird messages go away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was GHC Trac ticket [#9323](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9323), which gave the example

```
module Foo where

broken :: [Int]
broken = ()

ambiguous :: a -> String
ambiguous _ = show 0
```

"thomie" closed the ticket after Simon Peyton Jones left [this comment](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9323#comment:1) in July:

> Everything is fine in HEAD. (I don't know which of the many changes
>   between 7.8 and HEAD is responsible.)
>
> I'll add a regression test. But I don't propose to fix 7.8.
>
> Simon

Note: a peculiar but now-entrenched convention in GHC development circles is to refer to the official git `master` branch as `HEAD`.

Comment: Regarding your note at the end, you can refer to the tip or *head* of a Git branch, which is distinct from the `HEAD` symbolic reference; perhaps they just got the case wrong  (they write "HEAD" but they mean "head").